# Docker swarm mode load balancing not working as described

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

### Update

I believe the culprit is the master who does not appear to be listening on port 7946. `netstat` shows that 7946 is listening on the nodes, but not the master. When I check the syslogs for the nodes I see the following error

```
level=error msg="Failed to join memberlist [10.0.0.12] on retry: 1 error(s) occurred:\n\n* Failed to join 10.0.0.12: dial tcp 10.0.0.12:7946: getsockopt: connection refused"
```

### Original Post

I am running a three node Swarm Mode cluster in AWS; one master and two workers. This is **swarm mode** not to be confused with **docker swarm** from pre 1.12.

I created all of the services with docker-machine. Each machine is running Ubuntu 15.10 with Docker 1.12.3.

```
Linux swarm-master-01 4.2.0-42-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 28 21:26:26 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Using the master node I have created a service with the following

```
docker service create --replicas 1 --name myapp -p 3000 myapp
```

When I run `docker service ps myapp` I get the following output

```
ID                         NAME     IMAGE         NODE             DESIRED STATE  CURRENT STATE            ERROR
02awst8p9pezgpkfzqgz8z79t  myapp.1  myapp:latest  swarm-node-01    Running        Running 19 minutes ago
```

The running task is deployed to swarm-node-01.

I checked the auto-selected port which was published publicly

```
$ docker service inspect myapp | jq .[].Endpoint.Ports[].PublishedPort
30000
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/key-concepts/#load-balancing):

> External components, such as cloud load balancers, can access the service on the PublishedPort of **any node in the cluster whether or not the node is currently running the task for the service**. All nodes in the swarm route ingress connections to a running task instance.

But when I try to curl the nodes who do not have the task running I'm getting `connection refused`.

```
$ curl $(docker-machine ip swarm-node-01):30000/stats
{"uptime":"2016-11-09T14:48:35Z","requestCount":7,"statuses":{"200":7},"pid":1,"open_db_conns":0}

$ curl $(docker-machine ip swarm-node-02):30000/stats
curl: (7) Failed to connect to [the IP] port 30000: Connection refused
```

***note: I scrubbed the IP of node-02***

---

My Troubleshooting:

- The nodes are both properly connected to the swarm
- Scaling the service up to 5 (which inherently deploys the task to every node) makes curl work on every node, because the task is deployed to every node.

UPDATE 1

I initialized the swarm with

```
docker swarm init --advertise-addr 10.0.0.12:2377 --listen-addr 10.0.0.12:2377
```

I checked the syslogs from the nodes and I'm seeing the following errors

```
level=error msg="Failed to join memberlist [10.0.0.12] on retry: 1 error(s) occurred:\n\n* Failed to join 10.0.0.12: dial tcp 10.0.0.12:7946: getsockopt: connection refused"
```

I checked to see if the ingress port was listening and it doesn't seem to be

```
ubuntu@swarm-master-01:~$ sudo lsof -i :7946
ubuntu@swarm-master-01:~$ cat < /dev/tcp/10.0.0.12/7946
-bash: connect: Connection refused
-bash: /dev/tcp/10.0.0.12/7946: Connection refused
ubuntu@swarm-master-01:~$ cat < /dev/tcp/0.0.0.0/7946
-bash: connect: Connection refused
-bash: /dev/tcp/0.0.0.0/7946: Connection refused
```

Comment: What version of Docker are you running? Can you connect to node 2 and check the `netstat -lnt` to see if the port is listening?

Comment: What commands did you use to initiate _and_ join the swarm? What OS are you using?

Comment: I updated the post with some other things I've done

Comment: netstat -lnt shows that 7946 is listening on the nodes, but not the master. The nodes syslogs show `level=error msg="Failed to join memberlist [10.0.0.12] on retry: 1 error(s) occurred:\n\n* Failed to join 10.0.0.12: dial tcp 10.0.0.12:7946: getsockopt: connection refused"`

Comment: What command to join? What OS? Is port 30000 listening?

Comment: `docker swarm join --token <token> <master ip>:2377`. Ubuntu 15.10. Docker version 1.12.3.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get around the issue for now, but I don't know what initially caused it. The overlay network (port 7946) wasn't listening on swarm-master-01. I figured this out with netstat -nlt. I searched the syslogs and found these errors related to the port in the syslog.

```
Nov  8 20:28:20 ubuntu docker[23092]: time="2016-11-08T20:28:20.171385360Z" level=warning msg="2016/11/08 20:28:20 [ERR] memberlist: Failed TCP fallback ping: read tcp 10.0.0.85:54016->10.0.0.13:7946: i/o timeout"
Nov  9 18:26:17 swarm-node-01 docker[714]: time="2016-11-09T18:26:17.573441271Z" level=warning msg="2016/11/09 18:26:17 [ERR] memberlist: Failed to send indirect ping: write udp [::]:7946->10.0.0.38:7946: use of closed network connection"
```

For some reason docker refused to open this port and listen any more. Here is what I did (albeit undesirable) to circumvent the issue:

1. Created another node with docker-machine called swarm-master-02
2. Joined swarm-master-02 to the cluster as a master
3. Demoted master-01 which set master-02 as the leader
4. Restarted the docker daemon on each node (might not have been necessary)

Now all of the machines are working as expected except for swarm-master-01. One task is running on swarm-node-01 and curl works against all nodes by forwarding the traffic to the proper container on the proper node. However, swarm-master-01 refuses to listen on the overlay network and curl does not work against this node. I was only able to fix swarm-master-01 by completely removing it from the cluster, restarting the docker daemon, and joining it again as a master. Now 7946 is listening on that machine.